# Lazy Load, Lazier Load.. Control Fade Speed?

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

Normal lazy load plug in:

```
$(function() {          
    $("img").lazyload({
        placeholder : "img/grey.gif",
        effect      : "fadeIn"
    });
});
```

Can I control the speed of the `fadeIn` aspect say 0.9 or 1 second?

Is that possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's an `effectspeed` setting as well, for example:

```
$(function() {
  $("img").lazyload({ 
    placeholder : "img/grey.gif", 
    effect : "fadeIn", 
    effectspeed: 900 
  }); 
});
```

I don't have an API reference, as the site seems to be unstable at the moment, but you can see it used in the source here: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/jquery.lazyload.js